# Encrypting and Decrypting Files in Python

Tags: python, encryption

I want to encrypt and decrypt the file in Python.

The file will be very small, maybe 1 KB.

After investigation I have found some package for it: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-crypt
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptoshop/2.0.1
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyAesCrypt
https://github.com/surajsinghbisht054/py-filecipher

But now I am perplex what to use.

What is current (2017) standard?

Comment: Current standard is AES!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [`cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) package or ['PyNaCl'](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) are good places to start and under active development/maintenance. `PyNaCl` also explicitly supports both public and private key crypt.

[`simple-crypt`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-crypt) looks like it's getting a bit dated, and doesn't provide much more than a basic AES implementation for symmetric key crypt.

Comment: Link only answers contribute very little to StackOverflow.  Best not to answer if the question is off topic.